# Calling Rust function with function parameter from C results in SegFault

Tags: c, rust

I build a shared object with Rust and link against it in C. Compiling/Linking works fine but as soon as I call the function I get a SegFault.

Rust function declaration:
It consumes two integers/usize and a reference to a function that returns an integer/usize.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn show_loading_animation(from: usize,
                              to: usize,
                              progress_in_percentage_fn: &dyn Fn() -> usize) { ... }
```

I call it from C like this:

```
typedef long long usize; // 64 bit
extern void show_loading_animation(usize, usize, usize (*prog_fn)());

usize progress_reporter() {
    return 80l;
}

int main(void) {
    show_loading_animation(0, 100, &progress_reporter);
    return 0;
}
```

I assume `&dyn Fn()` is not compatible with a c function reference? I debugged into show_loading_animation with gdb. This is the assembly and the last line is where it crashes.

```
0000000000004530 <show_loading_animation>:
4530:       55                      push   %rbp
4531:       41 57                   push   %r15
4533:       41 56                   push   %r14
4535:       41 55                   push   %r13
4537:       41 54                   push   %r12
4539:       53                      push   %rbx
453a:       48 81 ec f8 00 00 00    sub    $0xf8,%rsp
4541:       48 89 94 24 e0 00 00    mov    %rdx,0xe0(%rsp)
4548:       00 
4549:       48 89 34 24             mov    %rsi,(%rsp)
454d:       48 39 fe                cmp    %rdi,%rsi
4550:       0f 82 a9 03 00 00       jb     48ff <show_loading_animation+0x3cf>
4556:       48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
4559:       48 8b 41 18             mov    0x18(%rcx),%rax
455d:       48 89 84 24 d8 00 00    mov    %rax,0xd8(%rsp)
4564:       00 
4565:       45 31 f6                xor    %r14d,%r14d
4568:       48 8d 6c 24 30          lea    0x30(%rsp),%rbp
456d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
4570:       48 8b bc 24 e0 00 00    mov    0xe0(%rsp),%rdi
4577:       00 
4578:       ff 94 24 d8 00 00 00    callq  *0xd8(%rsp) <-- crash
```

Comment: try to box it so it trait object will be heap allocated?

Comment: Note: The `&` in show_loading_animation(0, 100, &progress_reporter);` is not necessary: using the function name can only mean its address (contrary to `progress_reporter()'` which would mean to call it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a Rust callback function to pass to a FFI function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463426/how-do-i-create-a-rust-callback-function-to-pass-to-a-ffi-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&dyn T` is a fat pointer (basically a pointer to data and a pointer to vtable), C knows nothing about it internal structure so you need to use `type Fn = extern "C" fn() -> usize` instead.

Comment: Okay I try but I wanted to keep my Rust code free from C (like "extern C") so that I can use the lib from both, rust programs and c programs as smooth and easy as possible.

Comment: You probably should have another wrapper library for the C layer anyway. Very little idiomatic Rust functions have a C-compatible interface, most libraries should not use `#[no_mangle]` and libraries that do should have complicated names to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Well, you must use `extern "C"` to be able to interop with C, there is no other way. But you still can wrap this functions in Rust for better experience.

Comment: I implemented another function that consumes `extern "C" fn() -> usize`. This way it works! I added it as an answer to the question. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it this way. I provide two functions now, one for rust, one for FFI.

```
// translates extern c function reference to closure function for rust
#[no_mangle]
pub fn show_loading_animation_ffi(from: usize,
                                  to: usize,
                                  progress_in_percentage_fn: extern "C" fn() -> usize) {
    let fn_closure = || {
        progress_in_percentage_fn()
    };
    show_loading_animation(from, to, &fn_closure);
}
```

I removed `#[no_mangle]` from the pure rust function (see code above).