# Function callback from c using void*

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I have a library I need to use, which exposes a method that sets some callback. But that method takes a `void*`. That is later recasted into a `void(*)(int)` (funtion that takes an int).

Something like:

```c
#include "stdio.h"

typedef void (*callback)(int i);

void call_it(void* f) {
    callback fn = (callback) f;
    fn(10);
}
```

Then, I need to pass that callback from `rust`:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;

#[link(name = "demo", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    fn call_it(f: *mut c_void);
}

fn p(n: isize) {
    println!("{n}");
}

fn run<F: FnMut(isize) + 'static>(mut f: F) {
    let mut cb: &mut dyn FnMut(isize) = &mut f;
    let ptr = &mut cb as *mut &mut _ as *mut c_void;
    unsafe { call_it(ptr) };
}

fn main() {
    run(p);
}
```

Which runs into a SEGFAULT
`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

I have already checked some questions/answers, like:

[How do I create a Rust callback function to pass to a FFI function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31463792/1695172)

[How do I convert a Rust closure to a C-style callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270215/1695172)

[Calling Rust function with function parameter from C results in SegFault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470401/1695172)

And couldn't get my head around it.

I cannot change the `C` part, so what can I do from the `rust` side?

Comment: Casting between `void*` and function pointers isn't well-defined behavior. `void*` is only a generic type for object pointers. You should rethink the C design.

Comment: @Lundin That may be, but there are lots of poorly-written C libraries that do so regardless, and my guess is that OP is not the one writing the C library in question.

Comment: Exactly, sadly I cannot modify the C part...otherwise there would not be a C part to begin with :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider follow the example [Callbacks from C code to Rust functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#callbacks-from-c-code-to-rust-functions).

> The requirement for this is that the callback function is marked as extern with the correct calling convention to make it callable from C code.

Just turn your Rust code into:

```rs
use std::ffi::c_void;

#[link(name = "demo", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    fn call_it(f: *mut c_void);
}

extern "C" fn p(n: isize) {
    println!("{n}");
}

fn run(f: extern "C" fn(isize)) {
    unsafe { call_it(f as *mut c_void) };
}

fn main() {
    run(p);
}
```