# How do I safely wrap a callback to pass to Windows FFI?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, ffi, trampolines

I am trying to write a wrapper on top of winapi. I want to wrap functions that accept pointers for callback functions.

As an example, consider this:

```
// The unsafe callback type the FFI function accepts
type UnsafeCallback = unsafe extern "system" fn(exception_info: *mut ExceptionInfo) -> u32;

// The safe callback type my function should accept
type SafeCallback = fn(exception_info: &ConvertedExceptionInfo) -> u32;
```

The functions that will be used:

```
// The function exposed by winapi
unsafe extern "system" fn SetExceptionHandler(handler: UnsafeCallback);

// The function I want to expose in my library
fn SetExceptionHandler(handler: SafeCallback);
```

I want to create a wrapping function that looks like this:

```
unsafe extern "system" fn(exception_info: *mut ExceptionInfo) -> u32 {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        // Convert ExceptionInfo into ConvertedExceptionInfo. I know this is undefined behavior, but its only here
        // to demonstrate program flow
        let converted_exception_info: ConvertedExceptionInfo = (*exception_info).into();
        
        // Call the corresponding safe function (as to how we get the function pointer here, that's 
        // the whole question)
        return safe_callback(&converted_exception_info);
    });

    return match result {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(_) => _
    };
}
```

I can think of two possibilities to create this wrapping function:

1. #### Creating a wrapping function at runtime

   Create a closure or similar construct inside the safe
   `SetExceptionHandler` method.

   I have no idea how to get the closure across the FFI boundary.
2. #### Exposing a conversion macro and generating the function at compile time

   Edit the `SetExceptionHandler` function to accept the `UnsafeCallback`
   type.

   Then I could create a macro that generates the wrapping function at compile time and expose this macro to the user.

   I would have to expose unsafe extern parameters again, so it is not
   how I would prefer to do it.

   I have no idea how to structure such a macro or if this is even possible.

---

Is my first idea possible and feasible? If so, how could this be done?
If not, is writing a macro like the second idea possible and feasible? If so, how could this be done?

Based on

- [How do I create a Rust callback function to pass to a FFI function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31463426/155423)
- [How do I convert a Rust closure to a C-style callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32270030/155423)
- [How do I pass a closure through raw pointers as an argument to a C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38995701/155423)

I get the impression that my first idea is probably not possible with the exception of something called [trampolining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)).

Is trampolining possible in safe Rust and in this situation?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I create a Rust callback function to pass to a FFI function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31463426/155423); [How do I convert a Rust closure to a C-style callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32270030/155423); [How do I pass a closure through raw pointers as an argument to a C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38995701/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have edited my Question in Response. Thank you for your edit and links to simmilar Questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, i have found a blog post that explains a nice solution for the problem of wrapping callbacks. [Article here](https://www.platymuus.com/posts/2016/callbacks-without-userdata/)